# intelligent way to read another file for words to exclude while reading logs

Tags: grep, scripting, find, solaris

I want to have a separate text file which I can modify anytime for words to be excluded while grepping the logs file.
I have written below basic script to serve my purpose as of now.
in SunOS.
Please help.

```
find /export/home/testing/ -type f -name "apache_logs.txt" |while read file
  do  
    result=$(tail -50 $file |grep -v 'HTTP/1.1" 200'  $file)
    echo "$result" > result1.txt
    grep -v 'akamai/sureroute' | grep -v '/wp7/wp-login.php' | grep -v  'HTTP/1.0" 200' result1.txt  > result.txt; 
  done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` on Solaris to be able to read patterns from a file with `-f` and to do string comparisons using `-F`, then,

```sh
find /export/home/testing -type f -name apache_logs.txt -exec tail -n 50 {} \; |
/usr/xpg4/bin/grep -vF -f avoid.txt >result.txt
```

... where `avoid.txt` is a text file with a string on each line:

```
akamai/sureroute
/wp7/wp-login.php
HTTP/1.0" 200
HTTP/1.1" 200
```

This would look for regular files called `apache_logs.txt` in or under the directory `/export/home/testing`.  For each such file, `tail -n 50` is called to get the last 50 lines (as per your code; use `cat` in place of `tail -n 50` to get the whole contents of each file).

The resulting lines of text are piped through `/usr/xpg4/bin/grep` which will filter out (remove) each line that contains any of the substrings listed in the `avoid.txt` file.

The options used with `grep` are

- `-v` to invert the sense of the match (return lines *not* matching the pattern).
- `-F` to treat each pattern as a *string* and do string comparisons rather than regular expression matches. This allows the patterns in the file to contain characters that would otherwise be special in regular expressions, without escaping them.
- `-f avoid.txt` to read the patterns from the file `avoid.txt`.

The remaining lines of text are written to `result.txt`.

Without the `-F` option, you would have to be a bit careful with the patterns in `avoid.txt` and make them proper regular expressions.  Maybe something like

```
akamai/sureroute
/wp7/wp-login\.php
HTTP/1\.[01]" 200
```

---

If you only ever expect your `find` to find a *single file*, the code could be simplified into

```sh
tail -n 50 /path/to/apache_logs.txt |
/usr/xpg4/bin/grep -vF -f avoid.txt >result.txt
```

---

There are a few issues with your code:

- You don't quote variable expansions. See [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694)
- You needlessly store the result of a pipeline in a variable and then use `echo` to output the result to a file.
- Your first `tail` + `grep` pipeline uses `$file` on both sides of the pipe. This will cause `grep` to ignore the input from `tail`.
- Your second (longer) pipeline will use `result1.txt` only for the last `grep`, and the earlier `grep` commands will wait to read data from standard input (there will be none), and will eventually be killed when that last `grep` is done.

  A pipeline of this type usually looks like

  ```
  command inputfile | command | command | command
  ```

  i.e., you start with a command that reads data from some input file and writes to standard output. The output is read by the next command, and *its* output is read by the next, and so forth.
- The output file, `result.txt`, is *rewritten* from scratch for each found `apache_logs.txt` file, since you write to it using `>` in a loop.  This may be ok if you only ever expect the `find` to find a single file (in which case it would be better to not use `find` at all as the file would presumably not move around in the filesystem).
- You parse the output of `find` (the pathnames of the found files) using `read`.  This is generally a bad idea since pathnames on Unix may contain any character, including newline and backslash, except for the nul character (`\0`) which is a string terminator in the C programming language. See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)

Also related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your in detail reply. Worked like magic :)